# query to get the results of each row in table1 with a subquery of N maximum records found to meet a condition in table2

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying without success to calculate building heights in my city using the LIDAR satellite dataset.

**System specs**

- CPU: Core i7 6700k 4200MHz, 4 cores, 8 threads
- RAM: 32GB DDR4 3200mhz
- SSD: 1TB Samsung 970 EVO
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

**Postgres setup**

I am using the latest version of Postgres v12.1 database with PostGIS with the following tweaks recommended in different sources:

```
 shared_buffers = 256MB 
 maintenance_work_mem = 4GB
 max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 7
 max_parallel_workers = 7
 max_wal_size = 60GB
 min_wal_size = 90MB
 random_page_cost = 1.0
```

**Database setup**

- In the lidar table I have more than 3000 million rows, and in the buildings table more than 150000 rows.
- In the lidar table the GiST index was created: `CREATE INDEX lidar_idx ON lidar USING GIST (geom);`
- building table: | gid | geom |
- lidar table: | z | geom |

**Height calculation**

Currently in order to calculate the height of a building, it is necessary to check if each one of the 3000 million points (rows) is inside the area of each building and calculate the average of all the points found inside a building area.

The queries I have tried are taking forever (probably more than 5 days or even more) and I would like to simplify the query so that I can get the height of the building with a lot less points, without having to compare with all the insane 3000 million records each time for each building.

In example:

- For building with id1, I would like to get only the first 100 records found which are inside the building geometry area ( `ST_Within(l.geom, e.geom)` ), and once those 100 records are found, pass to the next building.
- For building with id2, I would like the same, get only the first 100 records found which are inside the building area.
- And so on..

**My main query is**

```
SELECT e.gid, AVG(l.z) AS height 
FROM lidar l, 
     buildings e 
WHERE ST_Within(l.geom, e.geom) 
GROUP BY e.gid) t
```

I have tried with another query, but I can not get it to work.

```
SELECT e.gid, AVG(l.z), COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE ST_Within(l.geom, e.geom)) AS gidc
FROM lidar l, buildings e
WHERE gidc < 100
GROUP BY e.gid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you really want to do this at all.  You should first try to [make the correct query faster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql-performance) rather than compromising correctness by working with an arbitrary (but not random) subset of the data.

But if you do want it, then you can use a lateral join.

```
SELECT e.gid from 
    buildings e cross join lateral 
    (select AVG(l.z) AS height FROM lidar l WHERE ST_Within(l.geom, e.geom) LIMIT 100)
```

> it is necessary to check if each one of the 3000million points (rows) is inside the area of each building and calculate the average of all the points found inside a building area.

This is exactly what a geometry index is for.  You don't need to look at every point to get just the ones inside the a building area.  If you don't have the right index, such as  `on lidar using gist (geom)`, then the lateral join query will also be awful.

Comment: Hi jjanes, really thank you so much for your help. I am testing it and it seems to work! wonderfull :) I am going to add the detailed setup I have for both tables, so we can also check what points are absolutely necessary to begin with. In this case I made all my tests with the lidar index added before, and with some postgreSql configuration improvements, but I was still having a lot of performance issues and that was the reason I was desesperately asking for some possible solution